# How to get rid of "The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js" error during the creation of a docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, angular-cli, docker-container, docker-image

Whenever I run the following command to create a Docker image,

```
docker build -t ehi-member-portal:v1.0.0 -f ./Dockerfile .
```

I get the following results

[image]

I'm not sure why it is complaining about Node version because I am currently running

[image]

And I am not sure why it is detecting v12.14.1 when you see I am running v14.20.0. I installed Node and NPM using NVM. I used this site as a reference to how to create the node and ngix image for a container.

Here is the contents of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /dist/src/app
RUN npm cache clean --force
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod


FROM nginx:latest AS ngi
COPY --from=builder /dist/ehi-member-portal /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY /nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

Here is more version information:

[image]

Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated. I need to figure this out.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the _text_ of the error messages, rather than a PNG rendering?  You should almost never include screen shots of terminal windows; the plain-text output is much easier to read and search for later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RUN npm run build --prod` is executed INSIDE the docker container, and node inside is not in required version.

Also you clearly states that you want to use node v12 with

```
FROM node:12.14-alpine AS builder
```

so this is why it is "detected" as 12 because this is the node version inside the container. Bump the version. You can use some of images listed here
https://hub.docker.com/_/node

eg

```
 FROM node:14.20.0-alpine AS builder
```

Comment: I am very new to Docker, so your answer is VERY helpful. I will be sure to remember that in future reference. Question though. Which container is it running inside since I haven't created a container yet?

Comment: Temporary one used for build process only.